# AngularJs ng-include IE doesn't show values from scope

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, scope

I have a problem with the ng-include and the scope in Internet Explorer (10)
In Firefox and Chrome (Canary) it works perfect.

I have a main Controller which changes the templates and the title ($scope.title).
When I open the app the startpage.html is loaded into the ng-include and the title changes.

But all scope variables within the ng-include only show that (the html templates which are included have their own controllers):

```
{{menu.Dish}}
```

But only in Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have a suggestion what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was an bugg with Angular and the placeholder attribute of a textarea. I used this code and then it started to work:

```
<textarea ng-attr-placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```